# не получается передать ArrayList в фрагмент

Tags: android

Привет народ!

задача: необходимо во фрагмент передать коллекцию своих кнопок расширенных от 
        android.widget.Button

мое решение: создаю класс Кнопка который наследуется от Button и реализует 
            интерфейс Parcelable, потом в активити с фрагментом создаю Bundle
            в который кидаю коллекцию кнопок при помощи putParcelableArrayList()
            и уже в фрагменте из Bundle достаю коллекцию

Вопрос:правильное ли решение.и как решить проблему в выделенном месте кода класса кнопки

кнопка:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.widget.Button;

public class LvlButton extends Button implements Parcelable{

    private int size;
    private String number;

    public LvlButton(Context context, String number , int size) {
        super(context);

        this.number = number;
        this.size = size;

        setText(number);
        setWidth(size);
        setHeight(size);
    }
//_______________________________________________________________
//здесь просит конструктор супер класса без параметров

    protected LvlButton(Parcel in) {
        size = in.readInt();
        number = in.readString();
    }
//_________________________________________________________________

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(size);
        dest.writeString(number);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<LvlButton> CREATOR = new Creator<LvlButton>() {
        @Override
        public LvlButton createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new LvlButton(in);
        }

        @Override
        public LvlButton[] newArray(int size) {
            return new LvlButton[size];
        }
    };
}
```

активити:

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainGameWindowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnLeft;
    private Button btnRight;
    private Button btnSound;
    private Button btnMusic;
    private Button btnLanguage;
    private Button btnGooglePlay;
    private Button btnExit;
    private ArrayList <LvlButton> listBtn;
    private Bundle bundle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_game_window_layout);

        listBtn = new ArrayList<LvlButton>();
        bundle = new Bundle();
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            listBtn.add(new LvlButton(this, String.valueOf(i),WindowConfiguration.getHeightDevice()/3));
        }
       bundle.putParcelableArrayList("btnList",listBtn);

        //устанавливаем настройки экрана (смотри класс WindowConfiguration)
        WindowConfiguration.setWindowConfig(this);
        WindowConfiguration.getSizeDevice(this);

        //получаем высоту устройства
        int heightDevice = WindowConfiguration.getHeightDevice();

        FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
        //устанавливаем высоту и ширену контейнера равную реальной высоте устройства
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(heightDevice, heightDevice));

        FragmentOfGameLevels fragment = new FragmentOfGameLevels();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

фрагмент:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FragmentOfGameLevels extends Fragment {

    private int widthBtn;
    private int heightBtn;
    private ArrayList<LvlButton> list;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        widthBtn = heightBtn= WindowConfiguration.getHeightDevice()/3;
        Log.i("mylog", String.valueOf(heightBtn)+ " "+ String.valueOf(widthBtn));

        TableLayout table = new TableLayout(context);

        list = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("btnList");

        TableRow row1 = new TableRow(context);
        TableRow row2 = new TableRow(context);
        TableRow row3 = new TableRow(context);

        row1.addView(list.get(0));
        row1.addView(list.get(1));
        row1.addView(list.get(2));

        table.addView(row1);
        table.addView(row2);
        table.addView(row3);

        return table;
    }
}
```

Comment: зачем может быть нужно передавать виджеты между контроллерами?

Answer (score 1):

Создавайте ваш фрагмент через конструкцию `newInstance`, передавая туда в качестве аргумента ваш список.

```
public static FragmentPlayer newInstance(Parcelable[] list) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArray("list", list);
    FragmentPlayer fragment = new FragmentPlayer();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

В самом фрагменте: `getArguments().getParcelableArray("list");`

Создавать фрагмент не через `new`, а через `Fragment.newInstance(list)`

Comment: попробую такой вариант, но все же главный вопрос нужно чтоб в списке были елементы. тобишь мои кнопки которые реализуют Parcelable. У меня проблема с передачей списка

Comment: используйте `putStringArrayList(...);` вместо `putParcelableArray(...)` и передавайте String[], предварительно записав туда ваш ArrayList. Например, вот так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/converting-arrayliststring-to-string-in-java