# задача с передачей объекта в фрагмент

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Помогите решить задачу, [в моем способе есть неразрешимая проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816855/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-arraylist-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82).

Собственно цель: есть коллекция, расширенных от Button кнопок, количество элементов допустим 100, мне необходимо создавать фрагменты с 9-ю кнопками в каждом, из этой коллекции.

Как в фрагмент передать элементы коллекции или саму коллекцию?

Comment: Используйте паттерн mvc. На что-то похожее отвечал здесь. Посмотрите, вам должно подойти https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664490/Как-передать-arraylistarraylistcustomobject-в-другую-активити/664499#664499

Comment: а без статики мона как-то?

Comment: @Jarvis_J речь идет не о коллекции данных, а о виджетах

Comment: опишите саму задачу подробнее (а не ваше [неверное] представление о ее решении), из вашего вопроса не понятна ни цель (зачем это нужно делать, возможно решение совсем другое, чем его представляете вы), ни поведение (что, зачем и когда должно происходить). Пока можно только сказать тоже, что и в других ваших вопросах по этой проблеме - виджеты не предназначены ни для складывания в какие то коллекции ни для  передачи между фрагментами, это визуальное отображение, работать вам надо с данными, а не их визуализацией

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю зачем хранить и передавать список кнопок, но можно попробовать как-то так:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String BUTTONS_ID = "button_list";

    public static SomeFragment newInstance(List<Button> buttons) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(BUTTONS_ID, buttons);
        SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<Button> buttons = (List<Button>) getArguments().getSerializable(BUTTONS_ID);
        ...
    }
}

public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    public void someMethod() {
        Fragment someFragment = SomeFragment.newInstance(buttonList);
    }
}
```

Comment: лучше всего попробовать решить действительную проблему, а не способствовать реализации какого то дикого костыля. Здесь классическая проблема XY.

Comment: Читал что вместо putSerializable лучше использовать putParcelable

Comment: @ pavlofff у меня с детства проблема- если я что-то придумал и оно ошибочно, самому найти ошибку практически не возможно.Хочу реализовать переключение между уровнями игры, где кнопки и есть соответствующие уровни

Comment: @pavlofff это костыль из учебника Харди и Филлипса "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" (издание 2016 года), в котором они утверждают, что это рекомендованный Гуглом идиоматический метод передачи данных между активностью и фрагментом. А вот по поводу передачи списка именно кнопок полностью согласен.

Comment: @ВиталийСупрун почему бы вам просто не создавать кнопки в фрагменте? А лучше даже на макете в неактивном состоянии, а в фрагменте делать активными кнопки доступных уровней.

Comment: кнопка своеобразная будет состоять из нескольких деталей: картинка с уровнем, если он пройден, если нет вопросительный -знак иль что-то типа того.Ниже картинки - звездочки за прохождение. может в будущем еще что

Comment: @ВиталийСупрун лучше создайте класс для хранения состояния игрока - какие уровни он прошёл, какие ачивки заработал и т.п. И при создании кнопки во фрагменте берите необходимые данные из этого класса.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось как-то так но боюсь очень уж плохой вариант
Фрагмент

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FragmentOfGameLevels extends Fragment {
    private TableRow row1;
    private TableRow row2;
    private TableRow row3;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        TableLayout table = new TableLayout(context);

        table.addView(row1);
        table.addView(row2);
        table.addView(row3);

        return table;
    }

    public void setBtnInFragment( Context context, ArrayList <LvlButton> array){
        row1 = new TableRow(context);
        row1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        row2 = new TableRow(context);
        row2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        row3 = new TableRow(context);
        row3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        row1.addView(array.get(0));
        row1.addView(array.get(1));
        row1.addView(array.get(2));

        row2.addView(array.get(3));
        row2.addView(array.get(4));
        row2.addView(array.get(5));

        row3.addView(array.get(6));
        row3.addView(array.get(7));
        row3.addView(array.get(8));

    }
}
```

Активити

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainGameWindowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnLeft;
    private Button btnRight;
    private Button btnSound;
    private Button btnMusic;
    private Button btnLanguage;
    private Button btnGooglePlay;
    private Button btnExit;
    private ArrayList <LvlButton> listBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_game_window_layout);

        //устанавливаем настройки экрана (смотри класс WindowConfiguration)
        WindowConfiguration.setWindowConfig(this);
        WindowConfiguration.getSizeDevice(this);

        listBtn = new ArrayList<LvlButton>();
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
            listBtn.add(new LvlButton(this, String.valueOf(i),WindowConfiguration.getHeightDevice()/3));
        }

        //получаем высоту устройства
        int heightDevice = WindowConfiguration.getHeightDevice();

        FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
        //устанавливаем высоту и ширену контейнера равную реальной высоте устройства
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(heightDevice, heightDevice));

        FragmentOfGameLevels fragment = new FragmentOfGameLevels();
        fragment.setBtnInFragment(this ,listBtn);

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
//____________________________________________________________________________________________
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        WindowConfiguration.setWindowConfig(this);
    }
}
```

правда не пойму почему сначала добавляются кнопки в строки,а потом строки в фрагмент ведь в коде поочередность описана наоборот